# Unable to Upload an URL containing Image file to Amazon S3 Android

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload the image from remote location to aws s3 without downloading the image locally. I tried with the following code and getting the exception. Can anyone help me on how to upload image to aws s3 using url.

```
PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest(amazonFileUploadLocationOriginal,keyName,new File("https://fbcdn-sphotos-f-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpf1/t1.0-9/401627_330699820286387_548864923_n.jpg"));
            PutObjectResult result = s3Client.putObject(putObjectRequest);
```

06-05 07:11:11.650: E/AndroidRuntime(1628): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-05 07:11:11.650: E/AndroidRuntime(1628): com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException: Unable to calculate MD5 hash: /https:/fbcdn-sphotos-f-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpf1/t1.0-9/401627_330699820286387_548864923_n.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
06-05 07:11:11.650: E/AndroidRuntime(1628):     at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.putObject(Unknown Source)

Answer (score 2):

you cannot pass remote url in File(). You first have to download it and then use it.